# Input equal (=) in local variable stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, stored-procedures

Simple question but wasting time to looking for the answer. I have stored procedure like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sinau]   

    @id varchar (max)
    AS
 BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare
@select varchar (4000),
@from varchar (4000),
@where varchar (4000),
@final varchar (4000)
-- Insert statements for procedure here
set @select = 'select *'
set @from = 'from permohonan'
set @where= 'where idpermohonan= '+@id
set @final=@select+@from+@where
execute (@final)
END
```

After I input parameter and exec that SP, the result is

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

Could you fix this ? Thanks

Comment: Use parameterised queries.  Search for `sp_executesql` and follow the tutorials.

Comment: Why define 3 different variables while instead you can use only one: `set @final = 'select * from permohonan where idpermohonan = ' + @id`?

Comment: `set @select = 'select * '
set @from = 'from permohonan '
set @where= 'where idpermohonan= '+@id`. **Add spaces** Anyway writing code like this is mess. You should really use parametrized `sp_executesql`

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik thanks but for some reason I need join 3 variable

Comment: When you are preparing SQL like this, your first step, before asking a community for help should be to *print* the generated SQL rather than trying to execute it. If you'd done so, it should be painfully obvious that `select *from permohonanwhere idpermohonan=` is wrong.

Comment: @lad2025 sorry. I dont understand. I think there is no between your answer and my question

Comment: @AufalAhdy Is it a joke? Just `SELECT @select+@from+@where`. You probably get `select *from permohonanwhere idpermohonan= ...`

Comment: sorry all. my fools. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add spaces:

```
set @select = 'select * '
set @from = 'from permohonan '
set @where= 'where idpermohonan= '+@id
```

because without it you get:

```
select *from permohonanwhere idpermohonan= ...
```

You should always check your query:

```
IF @debug = 1 
  PRINT @select+@from+@where;
```

**But for completness you should not concatenate string and use parametrized `sp_executesql`:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sinau]   
    @id varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @query = 
N'SELECT *
  FROM permohonan
  WHERE idpermohonan = @id;';

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
     @query,
     N'@id VARCHAR(MAX)',
     @id;
END
```

Using Dynamic SQL can be tricky so I strongly recommend to read **[`The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL`](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)**